# Variance Combinations of tomatoes

Tags: probability, combinations, variance, expected-value

> We put $n$ red tomatoes and $n$ green tomatoes into $n$ baskets at random, so that each basket contains two tomatoes. Let $X$ be the number of baskets containing one red and one green tomato. Find $\text{var}(X)$. Assume that $n \geq 10.$

For $k=1,2...,n$, we introduce random variables

$$X_k= \begin{cases} 1 \quad \text{ if the $k^{th}$ basket contains one red and one green tomato}\\ 0 \quad \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
Since each tomato is equally likely to end up in any of the $n$ baskets there are $2n \choose 2 $ ways to select a pair of tomatoes for the $k^{th}$ basket. Of which there are $ n \choose 1 $$n \choose 1$ ways to choose a red and green tomato ($n^2$ ways.) Consequently

$$ P(X_k=1)=\frac{n^2}{2n \choose 2}=\frac{n}{2n-1} $$
$$E[X]=\frac{n^2}{2n-1} $$

But how to find $E[X^2]$?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using indicator random variables.

Let $X_i$ be the indicator that box $i$ contains differently coloured tomatoes. Then $X=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ .

For any box $i$ the probability that $X_i=1$ is $\binom n1^2/\binom{2n}2$ or $n/(2n-1)$.   This is $\mathsf E(X_i)$.

Now as you had :$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X)&=\mathsf E(\sum_i X_i) \\ &= n~\mathsf E(X_1)\\  &= n^2/(2n-1)\end{align}$$

---

Similarly for any box $i$ the probability that $X_i=1$ is also $\mathsf E(X_i^2)$ since the indicator variable is either $0$ or $1$.   $\mathsf E(X_i^2)=1^2\mathsf P(X_i=1)+0^2\mathsf P(X_i=0)$

Next, for any two distinct boxes $i,j$, the probability that $X_i=1$ and $X_j=1$ is **something**.   This is $\mathsf E(X_iX_j)$ .

So we find

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X^2)&=\mathsf E((\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)(\sum_{j=1}^n X_j)) \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^n \mathsf E(X_i^2)+2\sum_{i=2}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\mathsf E(X_iX_j) \\ &= n^2/(2n-1) + n(n-1)\mathsf E(X_1X_2) \end{align}$$

Now what is the probability that two particular boxes each contain differently coloured tomatoes?  Back to you.

> Count the ways to select two from $n$ red tomatoes, two from $n$ green tomatos, and arrange them into two boxes of two differently coloured tomatoes.  Count the ways to select four from $2n$ tomatoes and arrange them into two boxes of two tomatoes. Divide and calculate.

Comment: Would $E[X_1X_2]= 1^2P(X_1=1)P(X_2=1)+1*0P(X_1=1)P(X_2=0) +0*1P(X_1=0)P(X_2=1)+ 0^21^2P(X_1=0)P(X_2=0)$ ?

Comment: No, not quite.  Those random variables are not independent.  However, yes, $\mathsf E(X_1X_2)= 1^2\mathsf P(X_1=1,X_2=1)+0$. @elcharlosmaster

Comment: Now, what is the probability for obtaining a red and green tomato in the first box, and a red and green tomato in the second, when selecting two tomatoes into each of the first two boxes?

Comment: $n^2*(n-1)^2$? I think?